# Spotfire - How to set value to a range filter

Tags: filter, range, spotfire

I have a column with data like 1,2,3, to 10
I am using this column as a range filter.

The user can change the range on the right side but on the left side of the range it should be default to 1 and 2. basically user cannot reduce the range below 2.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're going to have to create a calculated column with this defined range and use it as the filter. You can't set a lower threshold that I'm aware of.

Comment: ok Thanks @scsimon